# Drush fails on D8 sites but works on D7 sites - PHP Version Issue?

Tags: drush

We have a CentOS Linux 7 server with Plesk running several Drupal 7 and a few Drupal 8 sites.

Drush commands work fine on all D7 sites, but on all D8 sites any Drush command returns:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/path/to/drupal8site/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php on line 18

Running `drush status` on any D7 site returns a standard report:

```
 Drupal version                  :  7.65                                                                                      
 Site URI                        :  http://default                                                                            
 Database driver                 :  mysql                                                                                     
 Database hostname               :  localhost                                                                                 
 Database username               :  dbusername                                                                                  
 Database name                   :  dbname                                                                                  
 Database                        :  Connected                                                                                 
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                                                                                
 Drupal user                     :                                                                                            
 Default theme                   :  themename                                                                                  
 Administration theme            :  seven                                                                                     
 PHP executable                  :  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php                                                                
 PHP configuration               :  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc/php.ini                                                            
 PHP OS                          :  Linux                                                                                     
 Drush script                    :  /root/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php                                       
 Drush version                   :  8.1.17                                                                                    
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp                                                                                      
 Drush configuration             :                                                                                            
 Drush alias files               :  /var/www/path/to/drupal7site/httpdocs/sites/default/example.aliases.drushrc.php 
 Install profile                 :  minimal                                                                                   
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/vhosts/pinnbank.chronosdv.com/httpdocs                                           
 Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php                                                                
 Site path                       :  sites/default                                                                             
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files                                                                       
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Running `drush status` on a D8 site returns the `PHP Parse error` described above.
 My research has indicated that there is a disagreement about which PHP version Drush should be using.
I have tried multiple variations of `export DRUSH_PHP=/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php` but nothing I do seems to make any headway.

Does anyone have any ideas about what to try next?

Comment: you need drush >8.3 . http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Drush version issue. The Drush for D7 does not work for D8 and vise versa. See the [compatibility chart](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility). Rather than have one global Drush, you'll need to install the corresponding version of Drush locally/per project folder.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I confirmed the Drupal 8 site already has `vendor/drush/drush/drush` and `vendor/bin/drush`. The Drush version there is `drush_version=9.7.1`. I installed Drush Launcher following the instructions (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher). But if I try to run any Drush command from the Drupal 8 directory (e.g. `vendor/bin/drush status` I get the same PHP error I was getting before. `printenv` shows `DRUSH_PHP=/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php`. `php -v` shows `PHP 5.4.16 (cli)`, which I suspect is the problem now. Not sure how to override that. Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is Drush Launcher ignores the DRUSH_PHP env setting. I got it working with a "workaround". I modified my `.bashrc` file by adding `alias drupal8site-drush='/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/drupal8site.com/httpdocs/vendor/bin/drush'`. Now commands starting with `drupal8site-drush` in that directory run. The downside: I'll need to create an alias like this for each Drupal 8 site on the server. Fortunately, this server is a temporary solution for a few sites as we migrate D7 to D8.